# Problem with operator in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators, vb.net-to-c#

I'm converting vb code to c#

There is enum from telerik library:

```
namespace Telerik.Windows.Controls
{
    // Summary:
    //     Provides flags for enumerating the ViewModes supported by Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadScheduler.
    [Flags]
    public enum AvailableViewModes
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Enables Day view.
        Day = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Enables Week view.
        Week = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Enables Month view.
        Month = 4,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Enables Timeline view.
        Timeline = 8,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Enables All views.
        All = 15,
    }
}
```

and code in vb is

```
cal.AvailableViewModes = cal.AvailableViewModes And Not AvailableViewModes.All
```

Converter returns me

```
cal.AvailableViewModes = cal.AvailableViewModes & !AvailableViewModes.All
```

and it's not correct because cannot applu operator ! to opperand of this enum.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what converter tool are you using?

Comment: this one : http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitwise `not` operator is `~`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `~` operator to flip the bits.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following instead

```
cal.AvailableViewModes = cal.AvailableViewModes & (~AvailableViewModes.All)
```

The converter is having a problem here because `Not` in VB.Net has two purposes: Boolean and bitwise.  Which version is used depends on the type of the expression being targeted.  Since `Not` is being used on a numeric value in the VB.Net code it's actually using the bitwise version.  In C# the `~` operator is the equivalent.